# C# COM object and CreateDispatch

Tags: c#, c++, com, mfc

First of all: There is existing Code using CreateDispatch. The maintainer doesn't want to change the code for compatibility/convenience reasons (except for using a new TLB/GUID).

So I have to create COM object which works with this restrictions. Preferabbly in C# (but C++ is also fine).

Problem is: I have absolutely no experience with COM.

That's how far I got: I created a COM object in C#, registered it and got a tlb. I checked the Registry, there is an entry: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID{36E6BC94-308C-4952-84E6-109041990EF7}

Seems fine. Next step: creating a test program (C++). I created a C++ console project with MFC enabled, imported the tlb. Then I added the following lines to the main:

```
CInterface01 server;
COleException* pe = new COleException;
LPTSTR m = new TCHAR[255];

CoInitialize(NULL);

server.CreateDispatch(L"{36E6BC94-308C-4952-84E6-109041990EF7}", pe);
pe->GetErrorMessage(m, 255);
```

Somehow the CreateDispatch didn't work. In the Exception it reads: "Class not registered"(what?! it's in the registry). Even worse: It crashes the Visual Studio when I'm running the same program again.

It feels like the solution is near, but I have no idea whats going wrong.

Comment: CreateDispatch() has two overloads.  One takes a CLSID, you'd use the CLSIDFromString() helper function to convert that string you used.  The other takes a string, a ProgId.  You'd use (say) "ClassLibrary1.Class1".

Comment: `CLSIDFromProgID(L"ComServer2.CSCOMClass01", &id);` returns a NULL class, `CLSIDFromString(L"{36E6BC94-308C-4952-84E6-109041990EF7}", &id);` returns `id = {CLSID_ComServer2.CSCOMClass01}`, but the result is the same

Comment: Without any info at all how the .NET assembly was registered, you'll have to google "Class not registered".  Those 158 million hits has one that explains your problem.

Answer (score -1):

You need code like this:

```
//interface wrapper method implementations for
#import "YouTlbModule.tlb" no_namespace


//function
CoInitializeEx ( NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

IYouTlbModulePtr ptrYouTlbModule;

HRESULT hResult = ptrYouTlbModule.CreateInstance(OLESTR("Your.Component.Name"));

//test hResult

//Others function call

hResult = ptrYouTlbModule.Other(122, L"AAA");

//Call
int ret = ptrYouTlbInput.GetErrorMessage(m, 255);
```